# How to increment variable that is stored in variable with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have large block of html that is stored in a variable that contains a variable that should increment upon function.

Seems like this is very basic, yet couldn't figure out.

```
var x = 1,
    foo = '<p>This should count ' + x +'</p>';

$('#add').click(function () {
    $('#form-dynamic').append(form);
    x++;
});
```

Comment: Move `foo` inside the `click` handler.

Comment: Did you mean `x` instead of `count` and `form` instead of `foo`? Otherwise I can't make any connection.

Comment: @Bergi sorry, that was mistake.

Comment: The value of `foo` is a string. Even though you originally built it using the value of `x`, the string won't magically update if `x` changes. Think about this simplified example: `var a = 1; var b = 2 + x;`. At this point, `b` has the value `3`. Would you expect that if I do `a = 3`, `b` will also somehow update to `5`? Instead, whenever `x` changes have to "rebuild" `foo`.

Comment: :) yep, somehow I magically expected that. I completely forgot about the static variable.

Comment: I don't think "static variable" is the correct term here. You produced a (string) value. Values can either be mutable or immutable. Primitive values such as strings and numbers are *immutable*, meaning that they cannot be changed in any way. You can only create new values from them. Objects on the other hand are mutable. But even there, they can only be changed if they or one of their "containing values" is mutated.

Comment: Thank you for explaining things. Could you show me example for if I were to use an object as you explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable is static. So at any point, it will show the same value. To get the latest value, each time you click, move it inside the event handler to re-execute and re-assign the latest value:

```
var x = 1, foo;
$(function () {
  $('#add').click(function () {
    foo = '<p>This should count ' + x +'</p>';
    $('#form-dynamic').append(form);
    x++;
  });
});
```

And also change the `count++` to `x++`.

Comment: Yeah, it was meant to x++, somehow I wrote it here count++. Thank you for reminding me about static variables.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, your variable `x` is NOT a variable stored in another variable. It is a normal JS variable. So, just change `x` the way you change any variable.

```
var x = 1;        

$('#add').click(function () {
    $('#form-dynamic').append(form);
    foo = '<p>This should count ' + x +'</p>';
    x++;
});
```